# How to download file with id params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hello I try to download a jpeg image on rails by verifying that the Post exists and by recovering its id in parameter.

I try something but i got a error... I show you:

```
def download
  send_file '/public/uploads/posts/@image/image.jpg', :type => 'image/jpeg', :disposition => 'attachment', :x_sendfile => true
end

private

def set_image
  @image = Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

In my controller I have to in my routes get download.

And my `link_to` is:

```
<%= link_to "Download", download_posts_path %>
```

But rails say to me "Couldn't find Post without an ID".
I don't understand why... He dont't have the id but I dont't know why ?

Comment: Are u using filter? Before action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you use `set_image` in a `before_action` filter.

First you should pass the `post` instance or id to your route helper :

If your route takes a param e.g. `/posts/:id/download` :

```
<%= link_to "Download", download_posts_path(@post) %>
<%= link_to "Download", download_posts_path(@post.id) %>
```

If not you can pass it with a query parameter e.g. `posts/download/?id=1`

```
<%= link_to "Download", download_posts_path(id: @post.id) %>
```

Both solution will provide you a `params[:id]` in your controller. Otherwise `params[:id]` will be `nil` and `find` raises an error.

Then there's something wrong in the `download` action as @DileepNandanam pointed out. You're not using your `Post` instance (`@image`) at all, you're just passing `send_file` a string containing "@image", not the variable but just a string. You may want to use interpolation to build a valid path to your image. For example if your `@image` has a `:name` which could be `"image.jpg"` you would do it like this:

```
send_file "/public/uploads/posts/#{@image.name}"
```

Or you could name your images with the `post` id like `13.jpg` then you'll do :

```
send_file "/public/uploads/posts/#{@image.id}.jpg"
```

Or even create separate forlders with post's ids :

```
send_file "/public/uploads/posts/#{@image.id}/image.jpg"
```

Comment: Yes i using set_image in before_action sorry i forget to say it 
I go try this tks

Comment: I got a error with a quey parameters
Cannot read file /public/uploads/posts/@image/image.jpg
I tried with full path but it's the same thing

Comment: So it fixes your first issue :) Then what does a Post instance looks like (what are its attributes) ? And what is the final path you need to pass to `send_file` ? Can't work as you've done, you're not using `@image` variable in `download`.

Comment: @z3rtyyy_ I updated my answer with a beginning of solution for the second part of the issue. Please answer the question above so I can help you more.

Answer (score 1):

```
send_file "/public/uploads/posts/#{@image.image_file_name}/image.jpg", :type => 'image/jpeg', :disposition => 'attachment', :x_sendfile => true
```

The method image_file_name may varies depends on the attachment you have specified on model

A better way is to use the url for attachment like

```
send_file @image.image.url(:original)
```